# Parsing html page Objective C

Tags: html, xcode, xpath

I try to parse some website using XPath in Objective C (iOS). Everything is OK when I try to parse URL like "url.com/news", but when I parse something like this "ulr.com/news.html" I get `node is nil`. I think I have to save the content of news.html into local html file and then parse it maybe?
Here's the code that isn't working, thanks a lot.

```
NSURL *newsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ukr.net/news/politika.html"];
NSData *newsHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:newsURL];
TFHpple *newsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:newsHtmlData];
NSString *newsXpathQueryString = @"//article/section[@class='im'][1]/time";
NSArray *newsNodes = [newsParser searchWithXPathQuery:newsXpathQueryString];
```